# How to get photo and name from several ids at once

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I would like to show to my visitor their friends in an app. I get the id's of the friends in the app, but how can I get the names and pictures of them at once? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user has approved your app, you could this FQL query:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND is_app_user = 1
```

Full function:

```
function getFriends() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
          },
          function(response) {
            alert('Friends using app: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          }
        );
      }
    } , {perms:''}); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer.I need only friends, who is in the app. I get the id's with friends.getAppUsers. So I need name and picture for each id. I don't want to mace several request, but need a method to get name and pic for set of id's.

Comment: I updated my answer.  didnt see you were looking for just users of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fields` parameter in the API request:

```
fields=name,id,picture
```

By default the Graph API only returns `name` and `id`. Specifying that you want their profile picture in the `fields` list will also give you the picture. So the full request using the Javascript SDK would look something like this:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'name,id,picture' }, function(response) {
  // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: to get pictures for a set of IDs you already have, you have to use FQL like so:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user
  WHERE uid IN (uid1, uid2, uid3,...)
```

Replacing `uid1` etc. with your list of IDs.

Alternatively, you could use a [batch request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to issue several API requests to `/uidX/picture` at once. I don't know how much the javascript SDK will help you with that though; it may require more work than it's worth. I'd just go with the FQL.

Comment: But if I have a set of id's how can I get them all at once?

Comment: You'll have to use FQL for that (see my update). I don't know that the regular Graph API can do filtering like that (although I'd be interested to be proven wrong).